# 'Incorrect' result when rounding 0.45 to 1 digit using round()

Tags: r

I have been troubled by this simple question. I'd like to round numbers that has the last digit in 5 (like 0.45, or 0.85) to the format of 1 digit. When I used the `round()` function in R on, for example `0.45`, it didn't round up to `0.5`, but down to `0.4`:

```
round(x = 0.45, digits = 1)

#> 0.4
```

I am aware that it may relate to the features of floating-point numbers and the "round half to even" rounding method of the `round()` function. I am just wondering how can I get the 'correct' rounding in R?

Comment: As counter-intuitive as it may be, it is well-documented: see [`?round`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html), it says: *"Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard (see also ‘IEEE 754’) is expected to be used, ‘_go to the even digit_’."* This can be verified with `round(x = c(0.45, 0.55), digits = 1)` returning `c(0.4, 0.6)`.

Comment: As to how to round in the way that I (for one) was taught in school (more than a few years ago ;-), see the dupe-link, where `round2(x = c(0.45, 0.55), digits = 1)` returns `c(0.5, 0.6)` (what one might prefer).